# OpenSSL get deterministic random keys

Tags: c++, random, openssl, srand

For the sake of ease of deployment of a prototype of a distributed application I want to generate a list of openSSL keys that are deterministic based on some random seed.

I do already know that using srand(seed) does not work because openSSL uses a different soruce of randomness. I've checked out RAND_pseudo_bytes, but it seems to be using the same random source as the non-pseudo method so that one doesn't seem to be doing it either.

Is there a way to generate the SSL keys deterministically?

Comment: Generate "n" SSL keys randomly, save them somewhere, and then pick each saved one, one at a time, whenever you need one?

Comment: I thought about that possibility, but that would be significantly more work too, so I was wanting to check if there is an easier way first.